# How do I configure 4 monitors with xrandr?

Tags: x11, freebsd, xrandr

I have four monitors that I would like to arrange as follows:

```
                  [CARD0 MONITOR1]

[CARD1 MONITOR1]  [CARD1 MONITOR2]  [CARD0 MONITOR2]
```

The output from `xrandr` is as follows:

```
% xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5120 x 1024, maximum 8192 x 8192
GPU-0.DVI-I-0 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 340mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     75.02*+  70.00    60.02  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
GPU-0.DVI-I-1 connected primary 1280x1024+2560+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 337mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02    70.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
GPU-0.DVI-I-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
GPU-0.DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
GPU-1.DVI-I-0 connected 1280x1024+1280+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 337mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+  75.02    70.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
GPU-1.DVI-I-1 connected 1280x1024+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 330mm x 270mm
   1280x1024     75.02*+  60.02    60.02  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
```

I have tried for example to do this:

```
xrandr --output GPU-0.DVI-I-0 --screen 0 --output GPU-0.DVI-I-1 --screen 1 --right-of GPU-0.DVI-I-0
```

But I get:

```
Invalid screen number 1 (display has 1)
```

Could someone at least give some guidelines on how to use xrandr in this scenario?

Cards are NVIDIA QUADRO NVS290 (dual head).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may consider using [ARandR](https://www.freshports.org/x11/arandr) and then saving the layout. The saved layout is just a auto-generated `xrandr` script, which you can reuse and learn from.

Comment: That makes much more sense, thanks. Now I have the issue of having a 4 screen configuration where I have 3 aligned in the bottom and 1 centered at the top. This means that I can see only X range 1280-2560 for Y range 0-1024. For the Y range (1025-2048) I can see the whole width (0-3840). MWM puts everything by default on the top left (0-1280/0-1024) which has no monitor.

Comment: @M.E. How does that make more sense? It doesn't answer your question though it's a helpful one. Many people use xrandr as you do and you should  strive to find your answer and not rely on this.

Comment: It is not that common to set up a 4-6 monitors fixed installation so question arises if trying to do it with just `xrandr` makes sense or not. Using `arandr` is a valid workaround (and the only answer I got for the question). Said that, please feel free to add an answer with xrandr, I personally would appreciate it as I like to understand how base configuration works.